# Java unlimited semaphore

Tags: java, semaphore

Wondering how to **not** limit connections (or anything) using a Semaphore.

So you might be thinking, "That sounds dumb."  But, it simplifies my code a bit as it lets me treat the limited and unlimited cases uniformly.

Note I'm not looking for an advice on how to write something like

```
if(limited) {
    semaphore.acquire();
}
```

I can come up with dozens of ways to do this forking with if-statements.

More specifically I'm looking for an Apache Commons or Java solution.  This is just a simple situation in which I can write my own simple class to solve it, but when there are widely available utility solutions I prefer to use these.

Comment: 'Connections' probably isnt the right terminology to use. ***But***, whats stopping you from creating a Semaphore with Integer.MAX_VALUE permits? That sufficiently large to emulate 'unlimited'.

Comment: @Perception in my application sure, truth is in generality it's not like running 4 billion operations is out of the question (financial transactions, emails if you're Gmail or Yahoo...)

Answer (score 1):

Given that Semaphore is a class, not an interface, you will be forced to have some form of branching in the logic. In order to avoid sprinkling "if (flag)" checks all around your code, you could create an interface for use in your application that includes the acquire and release semantics of the Semaphore class. From that point, provide two implementations, one that is essentially a no-op, providing no protection whatsoever, and another class that delegates to java.util.concurrent.Semaphore - from this point you are in a position to use dependency injection to determine which implementation to use.

Again, the branching inevitably has to live someplace, this just moves it up and out of the business logic.

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific about what constraints I'm hoping to achieve.

Comment: I'd have to say that Perception's comment on your question is probably the most reasonable answer then. You are effectively wanting to use a Semaphore that can behave in a way which provides no resource guards - there's not likely to be a "widely available solution" for this particular use case. Happy hunting though!