# How to check if a thread is running in the ExecutorService Thread pool

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

How do i check if a thread is running in the pool of thread ExecutorService?

Background: 
  I want to synchronize between the threads in the Thread pool if there is a flag set.
So if the flag is set to true for synchronization, then I have to check if other Threads are running or wait for its completion and then invoke the blocking thread with synchronize, so that other threads would wait for this blocking thread to finish.

If flag is not set then no need to synchronize and could execute the threads in parallel.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us some context as to what/why you're doing?

Comment: tried thread.isAlive() ?

Comment: What do you mean? Do you mean whether a _task_ is running? There will always be `Threads` alive in an `ExecutorService`. Please post your code so that we can help you rather than guess at what you might need.

Comment: @exabrial Added the background of my question.

Comment: Can you take a step back and explain _why_ you want this.  Try to ask the question without talking about the specifics of what you need to accomplish.  Right now your question is too tied up with a specific solutiuon.

Comment: If you are running trigger-able daemon and do not want to have multiple runs for repeated requests, that executor service will not do, unless you couple it with an additional queue to ensure temporally close repeated requests do not result in the repeated runs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use a `Semaphore`.

This allows you to have a number of "permits" to do work. If you only want one task running at a time then have a `Semaphore` with one permit, otherwise have a `Semaphore` with a number of permits greater than the number of `Thread`s in the pool.

```
static class Worker implements Runnable {

    final Semaphore semaphore;

    public Worker(Semaphore semaphore) {
        this.semaphore = semaphore;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
            try {
                //do stuff
            } finally {
                semaphore.release();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int numThreads = 10;
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
    final Semaphore semaphore;
    boolean myflag = true;
    if (myflag) {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(1);
    } else {
        semaphore = new Semaphore(numThreads);
    }
    final Worker worker = new Worker(semaphore);
    executorService.submit(worker);
}
```

This example is a little contrived as you can just use a `newSingleThreadExecutor()` when you only need one task to run at a time - but I assume you know that and for some reason cannot.

**EDIT**

Having poked around a little to see if this can be tidied I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148785/java-unlimited-semaphore). This hints at a neater solution:

```
static interface TaskBlocker {

    void acquire();

    void release();
}

static class Worker implements Runnable {

    final TaskBlocker taskBlocker;

    public Worker(TaskBlocker taskBlocker) {
        this.taskBlocker = taskBlocker;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        taskBlocker.acquire();
        try {
            //do stuff
        } finally {
            taskBlocker.release();
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int numThreads = 10;
    final ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(numThreads);
    final TaskBlocker taskBlocker;
    boolean myflag = true;
    if (myflag) {
        taskBlocker = new TaskBlocker() {
            final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();

            @Override
            public void acquire() {
                lock.lock();
            }

            @Override
            public void release() {
                lock.unlock();
            }
        };
    } else {
        taskBlocker = new TaskBlocker() {
            @Override
            public void acquire() {
            }

            @Override
            public void release() {
            }
        };
    }
    final Worker worker = new Worker(taskBlocker);
    executorService.submit(worker);
}
```

Comment: @Bhargav what effect?

Comment: You know. making sure that only 1 task is running at anu given time

Comment: @Bhargav given that it has a **single `Thread`**, how would it do anything else?

Answer (score 4):

In short, you don't. Executors are not meant to be used that way. If you want to manage your threads manually, do it without Executors. If you use Executors, shift your thinking from `Thread`s to `Runnable`s. Make your Runnables or the Classes and methods thread-safe, using synchronization or any of the high-level abstractions in `java.util.concurrent`.

Answer (score 4):

> How do i check if a thread is running in the pool of thread ExecutorService?

If you just want to know if a thread is running in a specific `ExecutorService`, you can create the `ExecutorService` with a specific `ThreadFactory` and have it attach some special property to the thread, such as a special name.

```
private static final String EXECUTOR_THREADNAME_PREFIX = "ExecutorThread";

ThreadFactory threadFactory = new ThreadFactory() {

    private final AtomicInteger id = new AtomicInteger(0);

    @Override
    public Thread newThread(Runnable r) {
        Thread thread = new Thread(r);
        thread.setName(EXECUTOR_THREADNAME_PREFIX + "_" + id.incrementAndGet());
        return thread;
    }
};

myExecutor = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(threadFactory);
```

Then, in the thread, you simply check if the name starts with your prefix:

```
if (Thread.currentThread().getName().startsWith(EXECUTOR_THREADNAME_PREFIX)) {
    // In executor.
} else {
    // Not in executor.
}
```